# Running Java program on desktop

Tags: java, user-interface, deployment, installation, desktop-application

I don't want to run my Java program in Eclipse, I want to run it on my desktop like normal program, because I will present it so that it should not looks like amateur.

How can I convert it to desktop application type program?

Comment: [Pack all classes into a jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)

Comment: "*I want to run it on my desktop like normal program*" - But they are normal too :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669850/how-do-i-run-a-java-application-like-i-would-a-typical-program-using-a-shortcut

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.  It offers desktop integration (e.g. desktop shortcut or menu item with custom icon) & many other 'bells and whistles'.

Answer (score 2):

well, this is somewhat complicated question. when you compile you actually create a jar file, that you can run like a "normal" program. you can take that jar and run, but you need to know that your project my have dependencies on other .jars, pictures, or other type of files. therefor it may be a bit complicated. you can read more about it [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm) or [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm).

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373021/how-to-includes-all-images-in-jar-file-using-eclipse) is a question about making .jar with files(pictures). you might need it

Comment: More detailed info can be found on the [info-page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info), of [embedded-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embedded-resource)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your .jar file to an "executable"/"ready to run file" look at these possible [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are using mac or windows. I have a mac, and I just created an AppleScript to open my .class file that said:

do shell script "cd [filepath]
java [filename]"

and then saved it as an application and changed the icon, I don't know about windows though